# All subgroups normal $\implies$ abelian group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

This is , I think an easy problem just that I am not getting the catch of it. How to show whether or not the statement is true?

All subgroups of a group are normal$\implies$ the group is an abelian group?

I have been able to show the other way round.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is actually not true. A group for which all subgroups are normal is called a [Dedekind group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_group), and non-abelian ones are called "Hamiltonian". The smallest example is the quaternion group $Q_8$. [See this MO discussion for more info.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/25307/36146)

Comment: Thank you for your "Good" answer. Its very rare someone gives an extra link to further discussion for knowledge propagation, unless asked for. And please upvote if my question was worth it.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: consider $Q_{8}$, the quaternion group.